# in codeigniter, whats a good way of separating the session variable used for different website projects under same server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, variables

On my web development server, I have several **codeigniter** website projects going. I ran into the issue where one of my codeigniter website projects `session` variable was conflicting with another codeigniter website project's `session` variable. Both of those website projects are under the same server. So, is there a good way of distinguishing the variables between the website projects?

Again, both the websites are built on the codeigniter framework.  So, using codeigniter, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each application you can configure the session to be stored in the database with :

```
sess_use_database = true;
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: i am using database for session but then also conflict occurred
i an using CI default cart in two website in same server when i add product to cart in one website at a time another website cart in empty.
the what is the solution of this problem?
please help..

Comment: I think you can configure the session table name by application.

Comment: but i found the right solution 
the solution is :  you have to set different "sess_cookie_name"  in both application in config file

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a dB on the server side to track session info, you can specify a different db for each site.  In config.php look for the setting
$config['sess_table_name'] = ‘ci_sessions’;

Answer (score 1):

If both of your projects are under the same domain, then any session variables with the same name are going to conflict because the user's browser stores their session key in a cookie for that domain.  The best practice here would be to namespace your session variables; for instance, if you have want to have a "username" var in both projects "foo" and "bar", then name the two variables "foo_username" and "bar_username".  If you set a constant in the config .php file for each project with the prefix you want to use for the variables, you can then use that every time you get a session var.  For example, if you set an "APP_NAME" constant in your config.php and set it to "foo" for your first project, then you can set session vars with:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(APP_NAME.'_username', 'smg');
```

and retrieve with

```
$this->session->userdata(APP_NAME.'_username');
```

Comment: ya, but is there any other way using codeigniter's libraries or configs?